# Form validation in flutter passes despite not meeting conditions

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-textformfield

I am building a Flutter application with multiple TextFormFields. I create a reusable TextFormfield Widget to keep things modular. The problem is, when the submit button is clicked, even though the Text Form Fields are not valid, it runs like it is valid.

My TextFormField widget:

```
class AndroidTextField extends StatelessWidget {
  final ValueChanged<String> onChanged;
  final String Function(String?)? validator;
  const AndroidTextField(
      {Key? key,
      required this.onChanged,
      this.validator})
      : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    Size size = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
    return Container(
      width: size.width * .9,
      child: TextFormField(
        validator: validator,
        onChanged: onChanged,
    );
  }
}
```

How I use it in the Scaffold

```
                        AndroidTextField(
                            validator: (value) {
                              if (value == null || value.isEmpty) {
                                return 'Enter a valid name';
                              }
                              return '';
                            },
                            onChanged: (val) {
                              setState(() {
                                lastName = val;
                              });
                            }),
```

The form

```
  final _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
  @override
   Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
     body: Form(
        key: _formKey, 
        AndroidTextField(
            validator: (value) {
               if (value == null || value.isEmpty) {
               return 'Enter a valid name';
               }
               return '';
          },
            onChanged: (val) {
            setState(() {
            firstName = val;
            });
            }),

       TextButton(
         child: Text('Press),
         onPressed:(){
            if (_formKey.currentState!.validate()){
                  //do something
            }else{
                 //don't do the something
            }

        }
      ));

     }
```

Comment: I think you should return null instead of empty string

Comment: The return type 'Null' isn't a 'String', as required by the closure's context         -------                    I get that error when I return null

Comment: @SkyLurk `String Function(String?)?` looks strange. Try `String? Function(String?)`

Comment: final String? Function(String?) validator;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I feel a flutter validator should return `null` if valid, not an empty String.

So the code should be:

```
AndroidTextField(
 validator: (value) {
   if (value == null || value.isEmpty) {
     return 'Enter a valid name';
   }
   return null;
 }
...
```

Also, try:

`final String? Function(String?) validator;`

instead of

`final String Function(String?)? validator;`

Comment: When I return null, I get the error : The return type 'Null' isn't a 'String', as required by the closure's context